# If the unit ball is metrizable, are all balls metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(E,\|\cdot \|)$ a normed Banach space . Let $\sigma $ the weak topology on $E$. Let $B=\{x\in E\mid \|x\|\leq 1\}$. Suppose $(B,\sigma )$ is metrizable.

1) Will all balls be metrizable ?

2) Why $E$ won't be necessarily metrizable ?

---

**Attempts**

1) I would say yes using the following argument : Let $B_k=\{x\in E\mid \|x\|\leq k\}$. I define $$d_k(x,y)=d\left(\frac{x}{k},\frac{y}{k}\right)$$ where $d$ is the metric on $B$. Does it work ?

2) Since all ball are metrizable (if 1) is true), why can't we define a metric on $E$ as follow : if $x,y\in E$, let $B'$ a ball that contain $x$. It's metrizable, therefore, there is a metric $d$ on $B'$. Then the distance of $x,y$ is $d(x,y)$. Doesn't work ?

3) If 2) doesn't work, does $E$ is at least locally metrizable ? i.e. I can define a distance on all open that are bounded ? (or maybe it need to be convex ?)

Comment: Any bounded set can be $\subset$ in a ball.

Comment: "Locally metrizable" isn't a good name. Open balls in the norm topology can be not open in a coarser topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Works obviously.

(2) Fails because $d(x,y)$ isn't uniquely defined.

(3) The weak topology in a infinite dimensional Banach space is *never* metrizable: http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2008&task=show_msg&msg=2476.0001

In general, topological vector spaces are metrizable iff first countable ([Topological Vector Spaces IV: Completeness and Metrizability](https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/func-an-2007-2008/top-vs-4.pdf)).

Comment: But then we say that $E$ is locally metrizable ? (for (2))

Comment: @MSE, not exactly your question, but the closed unit ball in $l^p$ in the weak-* topology is metrizable: http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_analyst_2012&task=show_msg&msg=3965.0002.

Comment: @MSE, more details: http://www.math.unl.edu/~s-bbockel1/929/node13.html.